# Change image directly in the activity

Tags: java, android

I want to create a quiz app. Is there a way that when the user answers a question correctly and hits the "check" button, I don't need to create another activity but just change the image and answer in just one activity? I searched in many websites and I didn't found an answer to that.

I'm questioning that because I don't want to create ~130 activities, because this would be pretty big in terms of size.

Edit: My code for better explanation:

```
ImageView image = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.img);
        Drawable myDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.img1, null);
        image.setTag("img1");

        if (answer.equals("test1") && image.getTag() == "img1"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct answer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            myDrawable = ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.img2, null);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong answer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        image.setTag("img2");

        if (answer.equals("test2") && image.getTag() == "img2"){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Correct answer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Wrong answer!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        image.setImageDrawable(myDrawable);
```

Comment: If it helped please accept an answer. If you need help, feel free to ask us! :)

Answer (score 1):

To change the answer of a textview:

```
textview.setText("ANSWER")
```

To change the image:

```
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_image);
```

Where `img` is your view with the image. Let me know in the comments if this helped.

Comment: This should be the right answer. Changing image is more than just setting the tag of a view. When the user click on the button, change the image resource of the imageview.

Comment: @VitorPresa Should work...what problems are you having?

Comment: this should be an accepted answer for the question above.

Comment: for some reason my code is not working, I think I'm not using the tags properly, because the activity starts with no image.

Comment: @VitorPresa Please give me details on what's wrong, I need information to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to implement this logic using Single Activity and Single Fragment. This way you can instantiate your fragment by passing it the question no, so that it displays the question and options accordingly.
You just need to replace the fragment with the newly instantiated one in case of right answer. This way you will have good control over the logic for evaluating answer and UI

For more about fragments read [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html)